# xupload in Yii: How to handle uploaded files

Tags: yii-extensions, yii-xupload

I just managed to run xupload on Yii, the upload works fine.
Now i have to do something with the files being upload, i.e i have to loop through all the files uploaded by the user. Is there a simple way ? thanks in advance

Comment: do print_r($_FILES); so maybe we can help

Comment: $_FILES is always empty (i placed it in the controller action as well as in the view

Comment: than how do you know that the upload is working fine?

Comment: The Files are stored in the given directory

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following function:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileHelper#findFiles-detail

Comment: The problem is the following: Only authenticated users can upload files. I need to store (filename,username,etc) in a database.